# ssrs select drop down value as field name

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a requirement to display data for selected table and associated columns. I have two drop downs on SSRS report
Tablename (dropdown1) - I will get all tables in this
Columnname (dropdown2) - I will get all columns selected from tablename

For this, i have inserted a table on report and i have added 5 fields as a header as a column row as 1 to 5.
My requirement is to display columnname as selected value from dropdown2 as headers. If i select field1, field2, field3 from dropdown2 then my header should display header as field1, field2, field3. If i select only 2 fields then my header should consist only 2 headers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkAtw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play around with column visibility. You would setup the report with all possible table columns showing or hiding them based upon the parameter values (either using IndexOf or Split functions)